# Shell param doesn't pass with command

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, command

I use the following code to execute shell command, the issue is that when I put it as parameter which I should get from user it doesn't work but If I put it hard-coded it works.

> Working

```
VAL=`./test a | grep '^.(\bpass\b)?.$' | cut -d ' ' -g1`
```

> Not working

```
VAL=`./test a | grep ${param} | cut -d ' ' -g1`
```

In the not working version which I do `cat` to param I see the value printed OK, what could I miss when I pass `${param}` ?

Comment: Does the variable `param` really contain the correct value? Run the code under `-x` to verify it, or do an `echo param="$param"` before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters in shell are $1 $2 $3 etc... 
Right now what you typed is empty data.

You might need to put "" around the $1 parameter. And make sure that the value of $1 is indeed the correct value.

Comment: Depends what you want to do

Comment: if I do `echo  ${param}"`  I see the data so how should I change it ?

Comment: what I want is to get the value `VAL` as I got it when I use the first command (from the post...)

Comment: The part of '^.(\bpass\b)?.$' is the param?

Comment: when I change it to `VAL=`./test a | grep $1 | cut -d ' ' -g1`` it doesnt works

Comment: so it shouldnt be like "${param}" ?

Comment: $param doesn't mean anything - it is just empty space